# Crontab doesn't find a word

Tags: linux, shell-script, cron, environment-variables

```
 sid="GR1"

   if sapcontrol -prot PIPE -nr $sid -prot PIPE -function GetSystemInstanceList | grep 'GRAY' >> $LOGFILE
    then
       echo "STATE: SAP system is offline. (sapcontrol)" >> $LOGFILE
       echo "STATE: SAP system is offline. (sapcontrol)"
    else
       echo "ERROR: SAP system is still online. (SAP system has to be online)" >> $LOGFILE
       echo "ERROR: SAP system is still online. Check the logs. (sapcontrol)"
       exit 1 
    fi
```

This state script works manually fine, but if I execute it with crontab it doesn't. It doesn't find "GRAY" but it is gray. The sap log gets created, so the script gets executed, but it stops at this part of the script with SAP check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We face this kind of issue while using the packages is not from default RHEL. Cron may not run with the same environment as we run in the foreground.

we may be required to give full path of commands.

locate the path of `sapcontrol` by using the below command.

```
 whereis sapcontrol
```

it may be /bin/sapcontrol  or /usr/local/bin/sapcontrol

update the obtained full path in the script and give a try.

Comment: Setting `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` (if that's the correct location of the command) at the top of the script would also work.

Comment: Hi, nothing found with `whereis sapcontrol`.

Comment: @plattio check this location `/usr/sap/hostctrl/exe/sapcontrol`

Comment: Thank you very much it worked!
I dont know if you can help me with Oracle, but Crontab doesn't go into sqlplus:
``/oracle/GR1/121/bin/sqlplus / as sysdba <<EOF >> $LOGFILE
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
set echo on;
set serveroutput on;
STARTUP;
EXIT
EOF``

Comment: I've done a seperate question. Thank's for your help!